# Using finite difference to solve Cahn-Hilliard Equation in 2D using Octave

Tags: computational-physics, phase-transition, simulations, software

I am trying to use the finite difference method to solve the [Cahn-Hilliard equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Hilliard_equation) in 2D to study phase separation in metallic glasses. The equation is given as follows.
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}=M\nabla^2\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}-2k\nabla^2c\right] $$
Here $c$ is concentration also known as order parameter. M is mobility, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}$ is a nonlinear function of $c$.

My approach to solve this equation is to first calculate $\partial_cf-2k\nabla^2c$ using finite difference scheme and then solve the time-component of the PDE using Euler explicit method.
My Octave code is given as follows

```
clear;
clc;
%simulation factors
N=100;
M=100; %100
#disp("This is ",N, ",",M,"grid")
dx=1;
dy=1;
dt=1e-6;
#disp("dt=",dt,", dx=",dx," dy=",dy)

%thermodynamic factors
A=1.0
Mob=1.0
k=1.0
noise=0.02*rand(N,M);
c_0=0.48
c=c_0+noise;
framenum=0

  for t=1:5000
    disp(t)
    for i=1:N
      for j=1:N
        % PBC
        L=i-1;
        R=i+1;
        U=j-1;
        D=j+1;
        if(L==0) L=N;
        endif
        if(R==N+1) R=R-N;
        endif
        if(U==0) U=N;
        endif
        if(D==N+1) D=D-N;
        endif
        
        % COMPUTE DEL sq c
        dsq_c(i,j)= (c(L,j)+c(R,j)+c(U,i)+c(D,i)-4*c(i,j))/((dx)**2);
        %compute theta
        theta(i,j)=2*c(i,j)*(1-c(i,j))*(1-2*c(i,j))-2*k*dsq_c(i,j);
        
        
      endfor
   endfor
   for i=1:N
     for j=1:N
        % PBC
        L=i-1;
        R=i+1;
        U=j-1;
        D=j+1;
        if(L==0) L=N;
        endif
        if(R==N+1) R=R-N;
        endif
        if(U==0) U=N;
        endif
        if(D==N+1) D=D-N;
        endif
      
        del_sq_theta(i,j)=(theta(L,j)+theta(R,j)+theta(U,i)+theta(D,i)-4*theta(i,j))/((dx)**2);
        
     endfor
   endfor
   for i=1:N
     for j=1:N
       c_new(i,j)=c(i,j)+dt*M*del_sq_theta(i,j);
     endfor
   endfor
   c=c_new;
   figure(1)
    pcolor(c), shading interp, ...
     axis('off'), axis('equal'), title('initial composition');
     colorbar;
     if(mod(t,500)==0)
         framenum=framenum+1
         F(framenum)=getframe;
    endif
endfor
```

I am using a 100x100 grid and providing each element of the grid with an initial concentration of 0.48 + a noise factor to drive the simulation. Periodic Boundary Conditions have been used. The term inside the square brackets of CH equation has been taken as theta. As output I am getting symmetric figures instead of the observed microstructure formation in metallic glasses.

[image: initial concentration]

[image: final concentration]

```
dt=0.001;
dx=1.0;
dy=1.0
D=1.0;
kappa=1;
beta1=D*dt/(dx*dx);
beta2=D*dt/(dy*dy);
beta3=2*kappa*beta1/(dx*dx);
beta4=2*kappa*beta2/(dy*dy);

N=128;
M=128;
timesteps=12000;

noise=0.02*rand(N,M);
c_0=0.48
c=c_0+noise;
newc=zeros(N,M);
for i=1:N
  for j=1:M
    g(i,j)=2*c(i,j)*(1-c(i,j))*(1-2*c(i,j));
  end
end

for t=1:timesteps
  disp(t)
  for i=1:N
    for j=1:M
      L=i-1;
      LL=i-2;
      R=i+1;
      RR=i+2;
      U=j-1;
      UU=j-2;
      D=j+1;
      DD=j+2;
      if(LL<1) LL=LL+N;
      end
      if(L<1) L=L+N;
      end
      if(R>N) R=R-N;
      end
      if(RR>N)RR=RR-N ;
      end
      if(UU<1) UU=UU+N;
      end
      if(U<1) U=U+N;
      end
      if(D>N) D=D-N;
      end
      if(DD>N) DD=DD-N ;
      end
      

      T1=g(R,j)-2*g(i,j)+g(L,j);
      
      T2=g(i,U)-2*g(i,j)+g(i,D);
      
      T3=c(LL,j)-4*c(L,j)+6*c(i,j)-4*c(R,j)+c(RR,j);
      
      T4=c(i,UU)-4*c(i,U)+6*c(i,j)-4*c(i,D)+c(i,DD);
      
      newc(i,j) = c(i,j) + beta1*T1 + beta2*T2 - beta3*T3 - beta4*T4 ;


    end
  end
   
  c=newc;
   
end
figure(2)
    pcolor(c), shading interp, ...
     axis('off'), axis('equal'), title('final composition');
     colorbar;
```

[image: taking finite difference for 4th order]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't think there's anything inherently wrong using the two-step method for computing $\nabla^4c$, given that there are [well-known finite difference coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient), it might be better to just use the 2nd order 4th derivative term:
$$ \partial_x^4u=\frac{1}{\delta x^4}\left[u_{i-2}+u_{i+2}-4\left(u_{i-1}+u_{i+1}\right)+6u_i\right]$$
and directly apply the two gradients directly in a single step, rather than sweeping over the $N\times M$ grid three times per time-step.

I've not checked it, but you might want to determine the convergence condition on your coefficients (e.g., the [Courant-Friedrichs-Lewy condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant%E2%80%93Friedrichs%E2%80%93Lewy_condition)) to ensure that your timestep and spatial steps will not blow up to solution. Alternatively, you could solve the system using an implicit method instead (e.g., the [alternating direction implicit (ADI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating-direction_implicit_method)), which would allow you to ignore the CFL condition.

That said, I do, however, see two bad mistakes in your code.

The first is that you are using the number of cells in the $j$ direction, `M`, instead of the mobility `Mob` in updating $c\left(\mathbf x,\,t+\Delta t\right)$. You should be using,

```
for i=1:N
    for j=1:M
        c_new(i,j) = c(i,j) + dt * Mob * del_sq_theta(i,j)
    endfor
endfor
```

The second mistake is that, while your intent is to compute the Laplacian in two dimensions, you only do it in one. Look at your updates:

```
for i=1:N
      for j=1:N
        % PBC
        ...
        % COMPUTE DEL sq c
        dsq_c(i,j)= (c(L,j)+c(R,j)+c(U,i)+c(D,i)-4*c(i,j))/((dx)**2);
        % errors:                    ^ ^    ^ ^
```

The arrows point to the problematic indices; somehow, you managed to swap your them: it should be `c(i,U) + c(i,D)` here. I suspect that it is because of this error that you get a symmetric result.

Fixing these two mistakes, I end up with the following result (I did not, however, compare this to using $\nabla^2f'+\nabla^4c$ algorithm, though I suspect it would result in a similar result):
[image]

Comment: Don't know how these errors escaped my eye. Nevertheless upon fixing them I am not getting the same results as you are my result is completely [random](https://imgur.com/a/xGWBZbG) with no symmetry. I realised that we can use $\nabla^4 c$ expansion and I wrote a code for that too. This one also gives me a random [result](https://imgur.com/Jzydyut). Am I making some fundamental mistake here. I wrote the same code using spectral method and it works flawlessly.

Comment: For reference [this](https://imgur.com/QQktF8F) is what the result should look like

Comment: @kabir Your new code never updates `g(i,j)`, it maintains the value from $t=0$, so that might be one thing. Another thing is if your units make physical sense. You've set $D=\kappa=dx=1$, so I'm assuming that you've scaled your equation by a unit system, but is it complete? (that is, does $dt$ make sense in that case?)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It was mostly that g(i,j) term that was giving me errors. I wasn't updating it in multiple places.